# How to generate a list with two with range of other vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to save all the output in one `list (`elems[pos[ii]]`)`. My question is how can I save all the sequences in the same order to create a list with template. Example:
    //std::`list<char>go`,
    `go=elems[pos[ii]]`;
    i have not idea how to make it.

```
#include <algorithm>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using std::copy;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::vector;

    void combinations_recursive(const vector<char> &elems, unsigned long req_len,
                    vector<unsigned long> &pos, unsigned long depth,
                    unsigned long margin)
    {
        // Have we selected the number of required elements?
        if (depth >= req_len) {
            for (unsigned long ii = 0; ii < pos.size(); ++ii)
                cout << elems[pos[ii]];
            cout << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Are there enough remaining elements to be selected?
        // This test isn't required for the function to be correct, but
        // it can save a good amount of futile function calls.
        if ((elems.size() - margin) < (req_len - depth))
            return;

        // Try to select new elements to the right of the last selected one.
        for (unsigned long ii = margin; ii < elems.size(); ++ii) {
            pos[depth] = ii;
            combinations_recursive(elems, req_len, pos, depth + 1, ii + 1);
        }
        return;
    }

    void combinations(const vector<char> &elems, unsigned long req_len)
    {
        assert(req_len > 0 && req_len <= elems.size());
        vector<unsigned long> positions(req_len, 0);
        combinations_recursive(elems, req_len, positions, 0, 0);
    }

    const unsigned long num_elements = 7;
    const unsigned long comb_len = 6;

    int main()
    {
        vector<char> elements(num_elements);
        char elements_str[num_elements + 1] = "abcdefg";
        copy(elements_str, elements_str + num_elements, elements.begin());

        combinations(elements, comb_len);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected output is.

Comment: elems[pos[ii]] make a make a long unsigned char = abcdef,abcdfe,abdcfe for example , i want this string of character save in order in one unique list .

Comment: @hamlet `elems[pos[ii]]` is a unique character, to have the vector `elems` store strings you should create a `vector<string>`.

Comment: yes i make it but not found because inside of the vector<char>elem there is a vector <unsigned long>poss and one variable unsigned long , once you make othe vector just is posible between char and string not with elems[pos[ii]] thas combination make posible the string combination abcdef

Comment: @hamlet the unsigned vector isn't inside the character vector, you're using the values stored inside the unsigned vector to access the character vector at any given position. example: `vector<int>pos`, `ii=pos[0]` ii is an integer stored in pos, `vector<cha>cv;`, `cv[ii]` will yield a character, `cv[pos[0]]` will yield the same integer.

Comment: *I meant the same character, not the same integer

Comment: may you make one example of what you means.